# Diverse options give the same results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting a class on Python, and an assignment was to create a knock knock joke. I wanted to take it one step further, so I tried this code:

```
jokesetup=input('Do you want to hear a joke? Yes/No:')

if jokesetup=="yes" or "Yes": knockknock=input('Knock knock')

if jokesetup=="no" or "No": print('Then why are you here?')
```

But if I answer Yes or No, it still just says "Knock knock". What have I done wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `a == "b" or "B"` is the same as `(a == "b") or "B"`. You want `a in ("b", "B")` or `a == "b" or a == "B"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if jokesetup=="yes" or "Yes"
```

This means `True` as `"Yes"` is not an empty string.

You have to compare jokesetup with "Yes" also.

```
if jokesetup=="yes" or jokesetup=="Yes"
```

Boolean in Python:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp